# ASP.NET MVC 2 Preview/Beta Visual Studio Questions

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-2, .net-4.0

ASP.NET MVC 2 Beta was just released and I'm a bit confused as to what is required to run it.

Does it require .NET 4?

If I have an App that was created using Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2, can I port it to ASP.NET MVC 2 Beta by referencing the proper DLLs? If so what DLLs do I need?

Can I run ASP.NET MVC Beta 2 on .NET 4 ready hosting server (with ASP.NET MVC 2 Beta installed)?

In this [comment by Phil Haack](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/17/asp.net-mvc-2-beta-released.aspx#74907), he offers instructions on how to run "ASP.NET MVC 2 on VS2008 side by side with VS2010". If I do this setup, would I be able to run an ASP.NET MVC 2 Beta with VS 2010 Beta 2 but without the tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=4817cdb2-88ea-4af4-a455-f06b4c90fd2c&displaylang=en

If you read through the download page, you can see only .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 is necessary. So .NET Framework 4 is not required.

Answer (score 0):

This should help:  http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CheesyASPNETMVCProjectUpgraderForVisualStudio2010Beta1.aspx

**Update**

I misread the question.  Based on [this post by Phil Haack](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/17/asp.net-mvc-2-beta-released.aspx), it appears you can't migrate from VS 2010 Beta 2 to ASP.NET MVC 2 Beta:

> Unfortunately, because Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2 and ASP.NET MVC 2 Beta share components which are currently not in sync, running ASP.NET MVC 2 Beta on VS10 Beta 2 is not supported.

Comment: If I have a ASP.NET MVC 2 Preview created in VS 2010 Beta 2, how can I port it to ASP.NET MVC 2 Beta? That article dosen't have the public key info for ASP.NET MVC 2 Beta.

Comment: I know I can't run MVC 2 Beta on VS 2010 Beta 2, but how can I run an app created using MVC 2 Preview (comes with VS 2010 Beta 2) on a server with MVC 2 Beta installed?

Comment: Ok, so you have an MVC project that you wrote in VS 2010 Beta 2 and you want to run it on a server running MVC 2 Beta.  I would assume you _probably_ can provided the MVC assemblies expose the same functionality, but I don't know the strong names for the DLLs.  You might be able to do a similar process to the one described in my first link.  That is, just change your references as appropriate in the web.config.

Comment: @ Damovisa - Do you know where I can find the PublicKeyToken for the new assemblies, or are they the same?

Comment: @Baddie - have a look in the GAC.  In Windows Explorer, just go to C:\windows\assembly